# Can the preposition 'in' be omitted here?

Tags: grammar

Here are two sentences.
1. What are you doing in here?
2. What are you doing here?

What is the difference between the two sentences? (between No,1 and No,2 sentences)

Is there any grammar to omit preposition like above?